# Get Text from h1 with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I was asked to get a product name from a web.

I was asked to get this text:

> SEIKO 5 AUTOMATIC MENS STEEL VINTAGE JAPAN MADE BLACK DIAL WATCH RUN ORDER K

This is my BeautifulSoup code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


get = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/itm/SEIKO-5-AUTOMATIC-MENS-STEEL-VINTAGE-JAPAN-MADE-BLACK-DIAL-WATCH-RUN-ORDER-K/143420840058?epid=18032713872&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item21648c587a:g:ZzEAAOSw9MRdsI8v&enc=AQAEAAACQBPxNw%2BVj6nta7CKEs3N0qVBgKB1sCHq6imZgPqwOxGc8125XNy2Dq0slMe8clDZgTSnJdS4K5F5NyTF%2FwJExAng2G2%2FdtRUNYEnKcxoo4WXaAM5K%2BUxqDKTnmNGfgjTzpWCdoE50XlC7BXz3bBrJTY0vo62kBVR03HYvJwVCxnu8NEBiz4YMfAlPWDNnP2lVje46p22rKWDem6rHFqpoKtLDVHS8CaQER%2BqJxucEnw14LJIybRkfCmDuobZv%2F4F9Lhrl8xiPp%2Bbk6iRIu3UqqocBO%2FNyxW1aAa8QWkaJqtUy3g6Yue61yMEb0GY3BwO1%2BpVwkTOZLDvYHXZ%2FZEGNu%2F%2BYznes9jNtctDCr9Xv3QECsXyLDEOeo7LHh1srunEoRvK9T0AkS7oT%2BI3%2B%2BtD5fGnpJJu%2FJ3MdktqvgnTwieipeZTrGsHiQ8iL1nWm0CJcMbe2UUELEG%2BLHPNSSkRcUVBWnoPuOE5FjuyFHR1ujG2TgGLfN8HlO6ZyfNWz0K%2Bc4zjo7wBPnJdffcn6p8kLHWhbFyMyIY1Jc8yZBl20mlA29S%2BN%2Bw0e3uZDHK%2BIyCBctbYgGxaQM6Aevcdx0OcXl%2Fy7aDoRTqhBue9OYrAa3fEQf6ObFqtCbiEiXTioQZZJfrC%2FXfbq36oMTuQAFRvH2ahowGoPhSQkE1Jn73QLI%2FGXVynHIG2KdQSbX4eU%2FgoGy9y5WIvvUL9Xxy4ltNvTtCpjg5XlY8VxDv4M2gsLY3C0SRv7LNELk%2FitBSjfuUjzg%3D%3D&checksum=143420840058aa89790ec2164a5caf16644bb1bfd7c8&enc=AQAEAAACQBPxNw%2BVj6nta7CKEs3N0qVBgKB1sCHq6imZgPqwOxGc8125XNy2Dq0slMe8clDZgTSnJdS4K5F5NyTF%2FwJExAng2G2%2FdtRUNYEnKcxoo4WXaAM5K%2BUxqDKTnmNGfgjTzpWCdoE50XlC7BXz3bBrJTY0vo62kBVR03HYvJwVCxnu8NEBiz4YMfAlPWDNnP2lVje46p22rKWDem6rHFqpoKtLDVHS8CaQER%2BqJxucEnw14LJIybRkfCmDuobZv%2F4F9Lhrl8xiPp%2Bbk6iRIu3UqqocBO%2FNyxW1aAa8QWkaJqtUy3g6Yue61yMEb0GY3BwO1%2BpVwkTOZLDvYHXZ%2FZEGNu%2F%2BYznes9jNtctDCr9Xv3QECsXyLDEOeo7LHh1srunEoRvK9T0AkS7oT%2BI3%2B%2BtD5fGnpJJu%2FJ3MdktqvgnTwieipeZTrGsHiQ8iL1nWm0CJcMbe2UUELEG%2BLHPNSSkRcUVBWnoPuOE5FjuyFHR1ujG2TgGLfN8HlO6ZyfNWz0K%2Bc4zjo7wBPnJdffcn6p8kLHWhbFyMyIY1Jc8yZBl20mlA29S%2BN%2Bw0e3uZDHK%2BIyCBctbYgGxaQM6Aevcdx0OcXl%2Fy7aDoRTqhBue9OYrAa3fEQf6ObFqtCbiEiXTioQZZJfrC%2FXfbq36oMTuQAFRvH2ahowGoPhSQkE1Jn73QLI%2FGXVynHIG2KdQSbX4eU%2FgoGy9y5WIvvUL9Xxy4ltNvTtCpjg5XlY8VxDv4M2gsLY3C0SRv7LNELk%2FitBSjfuUjzg%3D%3D&checksum=143420840058aa89790ec2164a5caf16644bb1bfd7c8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(get.text, 'lxml')

company = soup.select('h1.it-ttl')[0].text.strip()
print(company)
```

The HTML from the code is:

```
<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name">
<span class="g-hdn">Details about   
</span> 
SEIKO 5 AUTOMATIC MENS STEEL VINTAGE JAPAN MADE BLACK DIAL WATCH RUN ORDER K
</h1>
```

Instead of the desired text, I get this:

> Details about    SEIKO 5 AUTOMATIC MENS STEEL VINTAGE JAPAN MADE BLACK DIAL WATCH RUN ORDER K

How can I extract only the product name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


get = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/itm/SEIKO-5-AUTOMATIC-MENS-STEEL-VINTAGE-JAPAN-MADE-BLACK-DIAL-WATCH-RUN-ORDER-K/143420840058?epid=18032713872&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item21648c587a:g:ZzEAAOSw9MRdsI8v&enc=AQAEAAACQBPxNw%2BVj6nta7CKEs3N0qVBgKB1sCHq6imZgPqwOxGc8125XNy2Dq0slMe8clDZgTSnJdS4K5F5NyTF%2FwJExAng2G2%2FdtRUNYEnKcxoo4WXaAM5K%2BUxqDKTnmNGfgjTzpWCdoE50XlC7BXz3bBrJTY0vo62kBVR03HYvJwVCxnu8NEBiz4YMfAlPWDNnP2lVje46p22rKWDem6rHFqpoKtLDVHS8CaQER%2BqJxucEnw14LJIybRkfCmDuobZv%2F4F9Lhrl8xiPp%2Bbk6iRIu3UqqocBO%2FNyxW1aAa8QWkaJqtUy3g6Yue61yMEb0GY3BwO1%2BpVwkTOZLDvYHXZ%2FZEGNu%2F%2BYznes9jNtctDCr9Xv3QECsXyLDEOeo7LHh1srunEoRvK9T0AkS7oT%2BI3%2B%2BtD5fGnpJJu%2FJ3MdktqvgnTwieipeZTrGsHiQ8iL1nWm0CJcMbe2UUELEG%2BLHPNSSkRcUVBWnoPuOE5FjuyFHR1ujG2TgGLfN8HlO6ZyfNWz0K%2Bc4zjo7wBPnJdffcn6p8kLHWhbFyMyIY1Jc8yZBl20mlA29S%2BN%2Bw0e3uZDHK%2BIyCBctbYgGxaQM6Aevcdx0OcXl%2Fy7aDoRTqhBue9OYrAa3fEQf6ObFqtCbiEiXTioQZZJfrC%2FXfbq36oMTuQAFRvH2ahowGoPhSQkE1Jn73QLI%2FGXVynHIG2KdQSbX4eU%2FgoGy9y5WIvvUL9Xxy4ltNvTtCpjg5XlY8VxDv4M2gsLY3C0SRv7LNELk%2FitBSjfuUjzg%3D%3D&checksum=143420840058aa89790ec2164a5caf16644bb1bfd7c8&enc=AQAEAAACQBPxNw%2BVj6nta7CKEs3N0qVBgKB1sCHq6imZgPqwOxGc8125XNy2Dq0slMe8clDZgTSnJdS4K5F5NyTF%2FwJExAng2G2%2FdtRUNYEnKcxoo4WXaAM5K%2BUxqDKTnmNGfgjTzpWCdoE50XlC7BXz3bBrJTY0vo62kBVR03HYvJwVCxnu8NEBiz4YMfAlPWDNnP2lVje46p22rKWDem6rHFqpoKtLDVHS8CaQER%2BqJxucEnw14LJIybRkfCmDuobZv%2F4F9Lhrl8xiPp%2Bbk6iRIu3UqqocBO%2FNyxW1aAa8QWkaJqtUy3g6Yue61yMEb0GY3BwO1%2BpVwkTOZLDvYHXZ%2FZEGNu%2F%2BYznes9jNtctDCr9Xv3QECsXyLDEOeo7LHh1srunEoRvK9T0AkS7oT%2BI3%2B%2BtD5fGnpJJu%2FJ3MdktqvgnTwieipeZTrGsHiQ8iL1nWm0CJcMbe2UUELEG%2BLHPNSSkRcUVBWnoPuOE5FjuyFHR1ujG2TgGLfN8HlO6ZyfNWz0K%2Bc4zjo7wBPnJdffcn6p8kLHWhbFyMyIY1Jc8yZBl20mlA29S%2BN%2Bw0e3uZDHK%2BIyCBctbYgGxaQM6Aevcdx0OcXl%2Fy7aDoRTqhBue9OYrAa3fEQf6ObFqtCbiEiXTioQZZJfrC%2FXfbq36oMTuQAFRvH2ahowGoPhSQkE1Jn73QLI%2FGXVynHIG2KdQSbX4eU%2FgoGy9y5WIvvUL9Xxy4ltNvTtCpjg5XlY8VxDv4M2gsLY3C0SRv7LNELk%2FitBSjfuUjzg%3D%3D&checksum=143420840058aa89790ec2164a5caf16644bb1bfd7c8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(get.text, 'html.parser')

company = soup.select('h1.it-ttl')[0].text.strip()
span_text = soup.select('span.g-hdn')[0].text.strip()

print(company)
print(span_text)
print(company.lstrip(span_text))
```

Since the span tag is nested in the h1 tag, the necessary step is to extract the span text and remove it from the h1 tag with the lstrip method.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to add that it stills print the whitespace, so edit it like this 
> product_name = "".join(line.strip() for line in h1_text.lstrip(span_text).split('\n'))

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers